# compile both Java and Scala at runtime

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to compile some interdependent java and scala code at runtime in scala. I thought scala runtime compiler(reflection API) would compile Java as well just like scala's compiletime compiler, but it turns out it does not recognize Java's syntax.

Then I tried compiling java code with Java reflection and add them to the class path, then compile the scala code that depends on the java code compiled earlier.

Is there a way to do this more robustly for multiple files mixed with both Java and Scala? Java code might depend on the Scala code and some scala code might depend on some Java code as well...

Comment: You could use maven for building your project

Comment: the code is provided by user at runtime

Comment: You might run an `sbt` process to do that. sbt certainly compiles mixed Java/Scala projects. But then I think you need to have your sources in a directory on disk and the warm-up time for sbt might be not insignificant. It depends on how complex and fast your application needs to be.